# gnuplot: strange pattern on color palette

Tags: gnuplot

I am using a color palette like this:

```
set palette defined (0 '#0000ff', 1 '#ff0000')
```

I expect the color palette on the plot to be a smooth transition from blue to red but what I get is this:

[image]

As you can see there are like more transparent steps in between. What can I do to get a smooth transition?

Note: I am plotting to a png image using this terminal:

```
set terminal png size 1100,550
```

Comment: That can happen with a vector format (pdf, eps), but shouldn't happen with png. Which gnuplot version do you have? I cannot reproduce this with 5.0 and terminals `png` or `pngcairo`. BTW: Always use `pngcairo` rather than `png`, if you can.

Comment: I am using gnuplot 4.6.6 which is the newest build for Arch Linux at the moment. Didn`t know that version 5 is out since January. Actually using pngcairo helped! The cause seems to be that I also use a transparent fill style. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For completeness:

The issue seems to come from the combination of using transparent fillstyle together with png. I now use pngcairo as terminal and everything works as expected.